# Control what gets generated - Transpilation/Compilation Time version of *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

The goal is to generate 2 different apps from the same codebase, one for the user and another for the admin. They are very similar, and I just want to disable some blocks. The way I'm tackling this right now via `*ngIf` and an environment variable

```
User stuff

<div *ngIf="environment.adminVersion">
   Admin stuff
   <div (click)="adminFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

The whole point is that I want to make the user version lighter, and all the admin stuff is not required for the user in order to use the app. My question is, are those blocks being removed from the transpiled verson at all?

Is there also a way to achieve this en the logic?

```
class welcomePage() {
   userFunction() {
   }

   adminFunction() {
      if (environment.adminVersion) { 
         Do admin stuff...
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a C-preprocessor control equivalent in angular/typescript? What would be the best approach? I guess what I guess I'm looking for is something like this, which gets removed or added before it even compiles:

```
#define version admin

User stuff

#if version==admin

   Admin stuff
   <div (click)="adminFunction()"></div>

#endif
```

```
#if version==admin

class welcomePage() {
   userFunction() {
   }

   #if version==admin
   adminFunction() {
      if (environment.adminVersion) { 
         Do admin stuff...
      }
   }
   #endif
}
```

Comment: using lazy modules https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading you can make that only some "paths" are loaded (tipical e.g. and admin module to change a dbs), but it's not response your question about *ngIf. I think that Angular must load the entire component

Comment: To answer your first question: When the `*ngIf` condition fails, the elements will not be generated in the DOM. However in any case the user can simply open the sources and see the stuffs that are disabled for them.

Comment: @MichaelD Exactly, that's why I would like to be able to complete remove it from the app and generate two different apps, removing it from the DOM is not sufficient. But on the other hand, I don't want to maintain two completely different apps, it would be a lot of code duplication just to disable a few blocks, there must be a best practice for handling this kind of situation. Worst case scenario I can write my own pre-processor script and mark those sections some how, but I really don't like that option, there must be a better solution.

Comment: @Eliseo That works for a path approach, but I just want to dissable small components withing a page. So far as I know there are no lazy loaded components, that's why I'm looking for the option of generating two apps and somehow controlling what gets generated. I don't mind generating two apps, but I think avoiding two almost exactly codebases is a good idea.

Comment: I don't know if this link: https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093 can help you (i'm in hurry and I read it over)

Comment: @Eliseo That's interesting, but I think lazy loading has the vulnerability of potentially being bypassed, the user could go to the source code and request the module, I guess nothing prevents this... I think the 2 app approach is the most secure, but very interesting article, I will read it more carefully too.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but I believe it solves the same problem.

We use grunt as part of our build process, and we use the grunt-preprocess module to allow us to do exactly what you are attempting to do. It preprocesses your templates and source code to strip out code wrapped in @ifdef/@endif comments based on build variables.

https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess

Examples from the docs:

```
<body>
  <!-- @ifdef DEBUG -->
  <h1>Debugging mode - <!-- @echo RELEASE_TAG --> </h1>
  <!-- @endif -->
  <p>
  <!-- @include welcome_message.txt -->
  </p>
</body>
```

---

```
var configValue = '/* @echo FOO */' || 'default value';

// @ifdef DEBUG
someDebuggingCall()
// @endif
```

---

The example is around debugging, but it could easily be used for admin builds as well.

Not sure if you use grunt, but if not, perhaps there is something similar for your build tools.

Comment: Looks very promising, is there an easy way to integrate this with angular? Or how your build process look like?

Comment: From what I've been reading it is not a good idea to combine grunt with angular

Comment: We use grunt because we have been using it for years... and we pulled in angular after we were already using grunt.  We've made it work, but there are definitely hurdles to doing so.  I wouldn't start using grunt just for this pre-processor.  However, knowing it exists might help you find a parallel capability in webpack, etc.

Comment: you are right, can't unfortunately find something equivalent so far

Comment: I'll take a look and see if I can find anything or have any alternative suggestions.  What are you using to do your builds?  Straight webpack or something else?

Comment: You didn't reply if you were using webpack, but doing a search for 'webpack preprocessor' finds a number of possibilities:  https://github.com/jballant/webpack-strip-block https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-preprocessor https://github.com/PatrLind/webpack-preprocessor-loader etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hi these are some thought on what you need these might be helpful for you and or for some other therefor I'm leaving this here

1. If you need to do this with `*ngIf` the bundle size will not reduce. Because to work *ngIf the code should be there for preparation for both conditions (true/false).
2. You can use separate modules for both admin and user. Can use lazy modules to reduce bundle size on the first load. (Bundle size in here means what downloads to the browser in the first load)
3. Still you need to specify which bundle to download first according to the environment variable.
   Using Auth Guards you can set conditions on your routing
   or when login you can redirect to specific module part
4. In this approach, this will not reduce the size of the bundle which get builds but the chunk which downloads to the browser will has an considerable impact on the performance as you desire.

useful links,

[Auth Gurds](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)
[Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: The lazy loading approach is not an option, because then I need to duplicate a lot of modules and make a normal and an admin version. I would like to avoid that. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I would like to avoid that situation as it would be a lot of code duplication, and maintaining it would be rather painful as the admin shares a lot of functionality with the user version. As far as I know lazy loading components is not possible yet, that would be an option as I could encapsulate the admin functionality in a admin component that doesn't get loaded...

Comment: Apparently is possible lazy load components with Ivy now, https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8 I need to look into that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Webpack` on Typescript, I think it will give you the expected results when building different version for different devices/use-cases.

LINK for more INFO:
https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/build-toggles

Comment: This does not affect the angular templates though, right? It wouldn't reduce the bundle size in that sense, or am I wrong.

Comment: If process.env.NODE_ENV is set to “production”, it will evaluate to false, and the code won’t run. if you combine with a tool like UglifyJS that does minification and removal of dead code blocks, it will become dead code in a production and be stripped out, and by that reducing bundled code size and execution time.

Comment: I'm not convince that it will work with the angular templates. That's a run time thing, maybe it does work, but I think it wont be able to deduce it

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution which is more suitable for your requirement, I was doing this for template based project which was more efficient

As you want to control your templates according to your environment variable I suggest you split your HTML into two parts without `*ngIf`

For example,

```
  <div> user </div> <-- user/common.html
  <div> admin </div> <-- admin/common.html
```

Now you can keep this HTMLs inside your project and before you are building you can copy desired html and build your project.
That's it. But there are few complication to achieve.

Complications resolved,

1. If you are having more than 1 HTML to replace this would make it a exhausting process to copy single one of them. For this you can keep your HTMLs in a different folder but in same file structure as the project. So you can copy and replace. (Replace in the sense you can keep a default template inside the project)
2. Also you can automate copy/replace scenario with little bit of shell script coding.

This maybe look time consuming but you only have to do this once. And you can keep clean HTML and you would not need to implement separate components or modules only HTMLs would be sufficient.

This is little bit of our of box but suitable for template driven projects that you would not need to change your component files only the HTMLs

If you did not get this method I would love to explain it more.